# How to refesh Facebook opengraph meta data after posting on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

There are times when I post a blog post with certain FB metadata, publish it and share the post on my Facebook page and then realize that I've made a spelling mistake in the headline, or the `og:image` needs to be changed.

I change it on Wordpress and then I go to Facebook debug tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to scrape the new information.

That's fine. But the problem is that the post that I've already made on Facebook page (before the modifications) still show the same title/image etc.

**I've seen other pages change them even after posting. How can I do that?**

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

go to facebook developer site > tool > debug

enter

```
http://yousite.com?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING
```

or for post page

```
http://youtsite.com/post_id=998&fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING
```

try this it may solve the problem.

otherwise some other issue, can be check by curl php extension concept

Comment: Are you sure this will change the title and image of the post already published on Facebook?